# Make navigation bar transparent and change it to opaque while scrolling iOS 13

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, ios13

I am working on UIViewController that contains a UIScrollView and it is constraint to the top of the view like that.

[image]

for setting the transparency for the navigation bar I use the following function:

```
func makeTransparentNavigationBar() {
    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    
    navBarAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.navigationBarText]
    navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.navigationBarText]
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.navigationBarBackground.withAlphaComponent(0)
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```

However when I scroll up to a certain point I want to make it white opaque so i can add some text to the navigation title.
[image]

I have the following function for making an opaque navigation bar

```
func makeSolidtNavigationBar() {
    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    
    navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.navigationBarText]
    navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.navigationBarText]
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.navigationBarBackground.withAlphaComponent(1)
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```

To look like that:
[image]

The problem I am facing is that I can't call them one after the other: If I call makeSolidtNavigationBar() in my viewDidLoad when I call makeTransparentNavigationBar() it doesn't work and the other way around

any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You Can Use **LTNavigationBar** framework https://github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationBar

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?